# How to fix matplotib incompatibility

Tags: python, matplotlib

I needed to visualize a cube and decided to use matplotib for python.

For some reason, code refuses to run properly. I tried out code from geeksforgeeks and matplotlib documentation example, neither works.

Is there a compatibility issue or I am doing something wrong?

For exaple this code (from geeksforgeeks):

```
# Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Create axis
axes = [5, 5, 5]

# Create Data
data = np.ones(axes, dtype=np.bool)

# Control Transparency
alpha = 0.9

# Control colour
colors = np.empty(axes + [4], dtype=np.float32)

colors[0] = [1, 0, 0, alpha]  # red
colors[1] = [0, 1, 0, alpha]  # green
colors[2] = [0, 0, 1, alpha]  # blue
colors[3] = [1, 1, 0, alpha]  # yellow
colors[4] = [1, 1, 1, alpha]  # grey

# Plot figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Voxels is used to customizations of
# the sizes, positions and colors.
ax.voxels(data, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='grey')
```

Outputs:

```
    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Cube visualization\cube.py:10: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bool` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.  (This may have returned Python scalars in past versions.
  data = np.ones(axes, dtype=np.bool)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Cube visualization\cube.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = np.ones(axes, dtype=np.bool)
                               ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 284, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'. Did you mean: 'bool_'?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using the newest version for python and just istalled matplotib using `python -m pip install -U matplotlib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.bool` was deprecated long ago and recently removed in favor of the built-in `bool`, so just change `np.bool` with `bool`.

"tutorial" sites are almost always outdated as no one is revising them, so instead you should check the official documentation of [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html) and [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html), such as [cube documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html)

you are also missing a `plt.show()` at the end of your code.

Comment: If, e.g., the OP is using a Jupyter notebook, a `plt.show()` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've already upvoted Ahmed's answer, but I cannot resist posting the resulting image.

[image]
that, of course, is obtained using `data = np.ones(axes, dtype=bool)` in place of `data = np.ones(axes, dtype=np.bool)` (and other tricks, irrelevant to the OP question).